# Fusion Tables 500 response on csv import to private table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Since monday my Android app users have been getting a 500 return code from Fusion Tables whenever they try to save their data.

Within the app we convert all their geo data into csv format and POST it to Fusion Tables using an insert command.  Before Sunday this appears to have been working fine.  Starting on monday we are seeing problems like the the following logcat with 100% of our saves:

```
10-29 12:18:34.083: W/System.err(3650): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/[valid table ID redacted]/import?access_token=[valid access token redacted]
```

Despite the error message, manually checking the Fusion Tables shows no error and all seems fine.

Given the other problems with Drive on monday I'm guessing that the team rolled out some changes over the weekend.  Perhaps there was a change that means I need to terminate the stream with a special character or something.  Anyone else experiencing a similar problem or have any idea what is going on?

I'm up to about 30 complaints from users now and it's getting a bit old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe this is resolved now -- are you still getting the reports? If it's the problem we identified, the imports were in fact eventually completing even though an error status was returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Just retried it at 15.15 EST: no change.  I'll give it a couple more hours.

Comment: Appears to be resolved on our test devices as of 18.00 EST.

The last notifications from a user about the problem was at 19.30.  I've sent out a notification to those who submitted error reports asking them to try to save within the app again tomorrow morning.

I'll just wait until I get independent confirmation from some users that things are back to normal before I mark the problem as answered.

Comment: The problem appears to be fixed.  Thanks!